# setter method in Spring

Tags: spring

Do I need setter methods for instance variable to inject value into the object?

App:
    package com.process;

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("SpringBeans.xml");
        Person sh = (Person) context.getBean("Person");
        sh.displayname();
    }
}
```

Person:

```
package com.process;

public class Person {
    String name;

    public void displayname(){
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}


<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="Person" class="com.process.Person">
        <property name="name" value="Bob" />

    </bean>

</beans>
```

When I run the App it fails with the msg -

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'name' of bean class [com.process.Person]: Bean property 'name' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

It works only with the setter methods.

Question:

Do I need setter method for each instance variable?

Comment: Yes, spring will set values to the properties by setter only.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need setter method for each instance variable?

You need a setter method to set a `<property>` declared in the `<bean>` element.

You can have a setter that is not related to a field. For example

```
public class Person {
    public void setFunky(String value){
        System.out.println("random piece of code: " + value);
    }
}
```

and

```
<bean id="Person" class="com.process.Person">
    <property name="funky" value="let's get funky" />
</bean>
```

Spring thinks it's trying to set the field represented by the `setFunky()` method so it will execute it. You're not required to actually access/mutate a field.

Answer (score 0):

To inject the value of simple properties such as `primitives and Strings`, you can either use constructor based dependency injection or setter based dependency injection.

**Constructor based dependency injection:**

```
public class Person {
    String name;

    public Person(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}

<bean id="Person" class="com.process.Person">
       <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="Bob" />
</bean>
```

**Setter based dependency injection:**

```
public class Person {
    String name;

    public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}

<bean id="Person" class="com.process.Person">
        <property name="name" value="Bob" />
</bean>
```

But you cannot use `@Autowired` to inject simple properties such as `primitives, Strings`. Below statement is taken from [Spring framework reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-exceptions):

> Explicit dependencies in property and constructor-arg settings always override autowiring. You cannot autowire so-called simple properties such as primitives, Strings, and Classes (and arrays of such simple properties). This limitation is by-design.